# My Java program isn't printing results from the query I made to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, drjava

I made a program that makes a simple GUI for a login form. Just for testing purposes I made it so when you click the "Login" button, Java should just print out the query results from MySQL database. In MySQL I have a database schema called "test" and a table called "login". The login table only has 1 row: "1, angelo, password" under the columns: loginID, Username and Password.

MYSQL Username is root. Host is localhost port 3306. MySQL Server is currently running.

I have the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin" in my "Extra Classpath" folder for DrJava (that's the software I'm using to program).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

( CODE FOR THE GUI GOES HERE)

```
                Connection connection = null;

try {
    // Load the JDBC driver
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // MySQL MM JDBC driver
    Class.forName(driverName);

    // Create a connection to the database
    String serverName = "localhost:3306";
    String mydatabase = "test";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +  "/" + mydatabase; // a JDBC url
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

                    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from login");

                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println( rs.getString("username"));
                }
                st.close();
                rs.close();
                connection.close(); 


} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Could not find the database driver
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Could not connect to the database
}
```

Whenever I run this there are no errors, it's just that nothing prints out.

EDIT: WHen I add e.printStackTrace I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
at edu.rice.cs.plt.reflect.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:148)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at swing_sample$handler.actionPerformed(swing_sample.java:108)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Based on what I posted can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in `test.login`?

Comment: Are you sure it is not throwing errors ? Add `e.printStackTrace()` to cath block

Comment: I added  e.printStackTrace(); and changed the rs.getStr to ("Username").  I know for sure there is something in my test database schema in the login table.

I posted the errors I get when I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have using the row data to print in the following statement :

```
 System.out.println( rs.getString("angelo"));
```

you need to give the column name or column index to `rs.getString()`

for example:

```
 System.out.println( rs.getString("user_name"));
```

or

```
 System.out.println( rs.getString(1));// assuming what you are lookin for is found in the first column
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However even after fixing this and adding e.printStackTrace(); I now get problems.

Comment: @AngeloRivera have you added MySQL driver jar file to the class path?

Answer (score 0):

1. try printing the url after setting the variable url
   It shld look something like:  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
2. As pointed out by codeMan, please use the column name instead of data, in your case replace angelo with Username.

Answer (score 0):

**problem is with loading JDBC Driver...**
same `error` occurs in my application when i don't add `mysql-connector.jar` to my `build path`.
It seems your `classpath` is not set correctly.. have you added `mysql-connector.jar` to `build path`?

Comment: I have "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" in my folder for the "Extra Classpath" in DrJava.

Is there something else I have to do? (like edit Build Path in the code or somewhere else?)

Comment: your code works for me when i add mysql-connector.jar ... are u sure your mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin is jar file and not zip file... if it's zip file then first unzip it and give the location of jar file to your Extra Classpath

Answer (score 0):

your code is looks correct, i thing your code try to load some of classes which is not in your class, make sure all dependency class should be in your class path.

```
clean code and build your project .
```

it might solve your problem solve your issue.